# Swift App crash on reopening. How find error code?

Tags: swift, xcode

My app crash after reopening, but if I wait like a 1/2 minute it opens normal. 
How I can see error if xcode disconnect from phone when I close app?

Comment: Add carshlytics to your project. It helps you to know on which line it is crashing.

Comment: Also, consider putting some break points in your code at points you think might be creating the error. Take a look at the debugger / console area of Xcode too. Does that show anything about the error?

Comment: I would recommend adding a breakpoint in the app delegate to make an error area smaller. Then add some to the first view that is loaded in the viewDidLoad. Something that happened to me a lot is that a UI element was tied to IBOutlet that does not exist anymore and it causes a crash you maybe you should look for those.